# Get the latest 50 documents with .find() in mongodb (monk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, monk

I am trying to get the latest 50 documents with the line

```
const msgs = await messages.find({ 'group': this.id }, { limit: 50 })
```

but this only gets the oldest 50 documents instead of the latest ones

Any way i can solve this?

Comment: You need to sort the _id descending first

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the line which would indicate the timeframe of your document being created like `sort: {'createdAt': 'desc'}`.

This will allow you to get only the latest 50 documents based on the date (should be a type of `Date`) when they were created.

Otherwise, you would need to use some other property which would indicate the order of your documents being created (`id` is usually random value so sorting with it would not work as expected).

---

```
messages.find({ 'group': this.id })
.sort({'createdAt': 'desc'})
.limit(50)
.then(msgs => {
  console.log(msgs)
});
```

---

```
const msgs = await messages.find({ 'group': this.id }, { sort: {'createdAt': 'desc' }, limit: 50 })
```